# Kotlin throw NPE when using Lazy Delegate with Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

#### Problem

`Foo` data class can convert various type.

For efficient implementation, the property is implemented by using `lazy delegate`. But when I try to access the lazy property, I faced an NPE. When i use the convert function `toBar`, NPE does not occur.

```
//data from Retrofit response via GsonConverter
data class Foo(
    @SerializedName("type") val type: String,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: JsonElement
) {
    val asBar by lazy { // it's throw NPE
        Bar.fromJson(data)
    }
    val asVar by lazy {
        Var.fromJson(data)
    }

    fun toBar() = Bar.fromJson(data)
    fun toVar() = Var.fromJson(data)
}
```

## Usage in RecyclerViewAdapter (extends PagedListAdapter)

```
...
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    position: Int
) {
    when (holder) {
        is BarHolder -> getItem(position)?.asBar?.let(holder::bind) // NPE
        is VarHolder -> getItem(position)?.asVar?.let(holder::bind) // NPE
        //is BarHolder -> getItem(position)?.toBar()?.let(holder::bind) // it's work
        //is VarHolder -> getItem(position)?.toVar()?.let(holder::bind) // it's work

    }
}
```

#### Exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object kotlin.Lazy.getValue()' on a null object reference

Why is NPE happening? how to solve it?

Comment: Please share more details. What does getItem() do? Is there any serialization involved? If the Foo class is instantiated by some Json deserialization library, and not by your code calling the constructor, that might explain the problem. Think of how this class looks in Java.

Comment: @MateuszStefek Thks for your response. I attached more detail info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in the way Gson instantiates classes while deserializing JSON. Gson uses Java's [`Unsafe`](http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) in the [`UnsafeAllocator`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/UnsafeAllocator.java):

```java
Class<?> unsafeClass = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe");
Field f = unsafeClass.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
f.setAccessible(true);
final Object unsafe = f.get(null);
final Method allocateInstance = unsafeClass.getMethod("allocateInstance", Class.class);

return new UnsafeAllocator() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T newInstance(Class<T> c) throws Exception {
        assertInstantiable(c);
        return (T) allocateInstance.invoke(unsafe, c); // instantiation of the class
    }
}
```

What the call `allocateInstance.invoke(unsafe, c)` does is simply allocate the memory for the class without invoking its constructor. When the class is instantiated, Gson uses reflection to set its fields.

Now back to Kotlin and the `lazy` delegate. The `lazy { }` builder actually creates a `Lazy<T>` object. The method is invoked during the class initialization, i.e. after its constructor has been called.

So, if the constructor isn't invoked during the unsafe allocation, the `Lazy<T>` delegate won't be created and will hold a `null` value. Every access to the delegated property calls `getValue()` on the delegate and in this case results in a `NullPointerException`.

To solve it you can either use the methods you've already defined (`toBar()` and `toVar()`) or create computed properties `asBar` and `asVar` instead of lazy ones:

```
val asBar
    get() = Bar.fromJson(data)

val asVar
    get() = Var.fromJson(data)
```

However, maybe the better solution would be to leave the `Foo` class as a dumb wrapper for the data and move the converting logic outside.

Comment: Worth noting that this solution loses the 'lazy' init behavior.  With the above code the Bar and Var will be deserialized every time `asBar` or `asVal` gets called.  Definitely should be kept in mind if going this route.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use the no-arg (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin). The plugin will generate no-arg constructor, which will make Gson invoke the default constructor instead of using unsafe allocation